# Pull all users / events from eventbrite API

Tags: rest, eventbrite

I am currently trying to manage some analytic's between multiple API's including eventBrite. Is there a way to make a request such as

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/
```

to pull all users that are associated with eventBrite?? I am familiar that this is common with other RESTful API's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We don't have an endpoint for pulling all users on our platform. You can GET all organizers under a specific User with http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/users/#ebapi-get-users-id-organizers.

All of our User endpoints can be found here http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/users/#ebapi-users

Comment: Maybe not for ALL users on eventBrite but all the users associated with the account. 

How am I supposed to find a user id?

Comment: You can pull all Organizers under an account, but not all subusers. We are working on revamping subuser permissions so that there are no more subusers anymore, but everyone will be a User. You can access User Id's by calling the User ID endpoint http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/users/#ebapi-get-users-id. If you are calling this endpoint on your behalf or on the behalf of an authenticated user you can simply use 'me' in place of the ID.